# Data from url doesn't load. Although URL is correct

Tags: swift, networking, swift5

```
DispatchQueue.global().async{
        do{
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/friendface.json")!
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601


            let downloadedFriends = try decoder.decode([Friend].self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.friends = downloadedFriends
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

> It Prints: "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing."
>   **I checked url [hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/friendface.json) and it's correct**

Comment: Don't use `Data(contentsOf:)` for remote resources URL, use the proper `URLSession` method `dataTask`

Comment: **Never** print `error.localizedDescription` in a Decoding `catch` block. Print `error`, it tells you exactly what's wrong and where.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your Friend struct. You need to checkout that every field is correct. Although I highly recommend to use `app.quicktype.io` to automatically generate Codable Structures

Here is correct Friend structure:

```
// MARK: - Friend
struct Friend: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var isActive: Bool?
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var company, email, address, about: String?
    var registered: Date?
    var tags: [String]?
    var friends: [FriendElement]?
}

// MARK: - FriendElement
struct FriendElement: Codable {
    var id, name: String?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shynggys, I am also working with the JSONDecoder for the moment, and compared your code to mine.  I made a small change to your code in the async method of the DispatchQueue class, and got data back from the URL. Line 30 in the screen print.

I also used the Friend struct which David suggested, since you did not include all your code in the post.

```
import UIKit

struct Friend: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var isActive: Bool?
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var company, email, address, about: String?
    var registered: Date?
    var tags: [String]?
    var friends: [FriendElement]?
}

// MARK: - FriendElement
struct FriendElement: Codable {
    var id, name: String?
}

DispatchQueue.global().async{
    do{
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/friendface.json")!
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601

        let downloadedFriends = try decoder.decode([Friend].self, from: data)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let friends = downloadedFriends //remove self, and assign to friends
//            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print (friends)
        }
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Results in console:

[image]